# C# Visual Studio Return Exception When Viewing UI

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating a Windows Application through the Visual Studio 2017 using C#. I have no issue when compiling and running the codes. However, when I try to edit the UI, the designer **returns some exceptions and unable to open the UI**.

I have navigate through the codes and it does not show any error coming from the designer site. Is it something to do with my Visual Studio configuration?

[image]

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: What platform? Framework? Core? Was it always this way or was it changed? If you go into designer.cs and remove all mentions of ECustomCtrl.EGradPanel does the UI appear?

Comment: Note that designers get confused easily (and have always done so), the first thing you should try, is close visual studio and delete your bin and obj directories and restart. also as mentioned above, check your designer code to see if anything is munted

Comment: Did you manually edit the `designer.cs` file?  If you did, you probably messed something up.  Try remembering what you changed and change it back.  As @thegeneral has mentioned, the designers are a bit fragile

Comment: One thing I can be sure of is, whenever I open the designer UI from other PC, it will be able to load up the UI without any exception

Comment: @TheGeneral Let me try this out first.